# counting negative numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the counts for negative numbers in a 2d-array ( square- matix). In matrix if you go from up to down and left to write number increases. Logic here is to start from last column and proceed to the left. If you find the neg num then increase the row index and proceed the same way till the last row. I am getting the error in java code but not in python.

```
public class O_n 

{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

    int firstarray[][] = {{-2,-1,0},{-1,0,1},{0,1,2}};
    int secondarray[][] = {{-4,-3,-2},{-3,-2,-1},{-2,-1,0}};
    System.out.print ("First array has"+count_neg(firstarray));
    System.out.println("negative numbers");
    System.out.print ("Second array has"+count_neg(secondarray));
    System.out.println("negative numbers");
}

public static int count_neg(int x[][]){
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0; //rows
    int j = x.length - 1; //columns

    System.out.println("max column index is: "+j);
    while ( i >=0 && j<x.length){
        if (x[i][j] < 0){ // negative number
            count += (j + 1);// since j is an index...so j + 1
            i += 1;
        }
        else { // positive number
            j -= 1;
        }
    }
    return (count);
    }
}
```

I am getting this output

```
max column index is: 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at O_n.count_neg(O_n.java:22)
    at O_n.main(O_n.java:9)
/home/eos/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java 
returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What is wrong with this code? the same thing worked in python...

```
def count_neg(array):
    count = 0
    i = 0 # row
    j = len(array) -1 # col
    # since we are starting from right side

    while j >= 0 and i < len(array):
        if array[i][j] < 0: 
            count += (j + 1)
            i += 1
        else:
            j -= 1
    return count
print(count_neg([[-4,-3,-1,1],[-2,-2,1,2],[-1,1,2,3],[1,2,4,5]]))
```

Comment: Besides showing the working code on Python, could you edit your question and show us the expected result of your Java code?

Comment: first array has 3 negative numbers
Second array has 8 negative numbers



Comment out max column index is: line

Comment: Didn't get how the python code finds number of negative numbers! For me it only make sense if `count += (j + 1)` change to `count = j`. In this case you will find max column index with negative number in the whole matrix

Comment: j is an index...and j starts with length of an array -1. So if the array is 2*2 matrix, j = 1 isn't it? If x[0][1] is negative ..it should return 2 for row 1 since we are going from right to left...that is why j + 1...after that we will go to next row...

Comment: funny but your code is incorrect but return correct result because of test arrays. if switch few numbers in the arrays the results will be incorrect

Comment: Where do you find it incorrect?

Comment: @DishantMewada you can find test arrays in my answer with which your code return incorrect results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexes are reversed from the python version:

```
while j >= 0 and i < len(array)
```

To the Java version:

```
while (i >= 0 && j < x.length)
// Change to
while (j >= 0 && i < x.length)
```

Output:

```
max column index is: 2
3
```

If you are using Java8,  you can use streams to implement count_neg:

```
public static int countNeg(int x[][]) {
    long count = Stream.of(x)
            .flatMapToInt(arr -> IntStream.of(arr))
            .filter(i -> i < 0)
            .count();
    return Math.toIntExact(count);
}
```

Comment: Your function is great but isn't it a good practice to emphasize on algo than shortcut like this...just saying...thanks for the help...

Comment: @DishantMewada I wouldn't go as far a calling it bad practice. It's just a different way of doing the same thing. If your focus is to study algorithms, then by all means, focus on the algo's. If your focus is on learning the tools available in the toolkit then "heck why not". Bad practice is, not to use all the tools available to you, and not following standard naming conventions, in Java camelCase is preferred over snake_case so `countNeg` is better suited than `count_Neg`. Glad I could help.

Comment: @DishantMewada yes I agree, it's always better to learn the details well before you move to more advanced topics. Everything is built upon the basics, so yes your approach is correct, learn the basics well and then move on to the more advanced techniques. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

I would write the method like this, just go through the 2d array and increase `count` each time a negative number is found

```
public static int count_neg(int x[][]){
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
            if(x[i][j] < 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count);
}
```

Comment: No for this code big-O notation is O(n square) since there are two for loops...my code has O(n)...do you know any other method?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your algorithm don't find the count of negative numbers.

Here are the results of the python code:

`print(count_neg([[1, 1, -1],[1, 1, -1],[1, 1, -1]]))` **result - 9**

`print(count_neg([[1, 1, -1],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]))` **result - 3**

So the provided code finds sum of column indexes + 1 for some negative numbers, not all. And for your test arrays it's return pseudo correct counts.

To find the count of negative numbers in a two-dimentional array you just have to get each number, check if the one is less than zero and increase the counter by one if it's true. So it's impossible to get the correct result with complexity better than O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Here the correct code in Java of doing that:

```
public static int count_neg(int x[][]){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
            if(x[i][j] < 0) count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that matrix is sqaure matrix and always increasing from left to right and up to down...so matrix cant be [[1,1,-1],[1,1,-1],[1,1,-1].......for example it can be [[-2,-1,-1],[-1,0,1],[0,0,1]]

Comment: For most of the random patterns O(n) is not possible...that is why algos are important...

Comment: And there is correction in my code 


    while ( j >= 0 && i<x.length)

Comment: Finally got the idea of your answer) If numbers increase than the accepted answer is right - onec you find first negative number in a column you can skip all others as they are all negative as well

Comment: Just for clarity, even on average the algorithms is faster, it's **asymtotic time complexity** is still O(n*n) as it takes into account a negative schenario i.e. when all numbers are positive

Answer (score 1):

Here a small change in the algorithms to produce correct result with columns which don't contain negative numbers:

```
    while j >= 0 and i < len(array):
    if array[i][j] < 0:
        count += (j + 1)
        i += 1
    else:
        j -= 1
    if j < 0:
        i += 1
        j = len(array) - 1
```

You can test it with the following array `[[1,2,4,5],[-2,-2,1,2],[-1,1,2,3],[1,2,4,5]]`

Comment: For my question array cannot be [[1,2,4,5],[-2,-2,1,2],[-1,1,2,3],[1,2,4,5]] since 5 of x[0] is larger than 2 of x[1].....in columns also when you go from up to down the value increases....in rows left to right values of the element increases....